# innerHTML not updating

Tags: javascript, events, innerhtml

I am trying to update the innerHTML of an element but not getting any output.

Each time an image of a taco is clicked the price of the taco should be added to the total. The values are numbers, not strings.

Any help is appreciated, I'm stumped.

```js
(function() {

  var T1 = document.querySelector('#taco1');
  T1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
      var Total = document.getElementById("Total").textContent;
      var price = document.getElementById("p1").textContent;
      var nbrprice = parseInt(price);
      var nbrTotal = parseInt(Total);
      console.log("value of nbrprice is " + nbrprice)
      console.log("nbrprice is a " + typeof(nbrprice));
      console.log("nbrTotal is a " + typeof(nbrTotal));
      var sum = Number(price) + Number(Total);
      console.log("sum is a " + typeof(sum));
      console.log("value of sum is " + sum);;
    }
    var sumtxt = (sum + nbrprice);
    Total.innerHTML = sumtxt.toString();
    console.log(Total);
  }, false);

})();
```

```html
<div id='taco1'>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100" width="300" />
  <p>Taco One Price: <span id="p1">4</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div id='taco2'>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100" width="300" />
  <p>Taco Two Price: <span id="p2">5</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>Total: $<span id="Total">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `var Total` is inside the if.. that means it will not exist outside the scope of the if. You can move the variable to before the if... or re-create it before innerHTML.

Comment: Simple example to replicate your issue: `"foo".innerHTML = "bar";` doesn't magically update the content of any DOM element.

Comment: @wendelbsilva: That's incorrect. JavaScript has function scope, not block scope. Also if that was really the issue, the code would throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @FelixKling just tested on chrome console and the variable didnt existed if it didnt get inside the if. `if (false){ var j=10;} console.log(j);//doesnt work`... `if (true){ var j=10;} console.log(j);//works`. If the innerHTML is outside if, them Im assuming he will want to set it even if doesnt get inside the if... so its better to move the variable outside.

Comment: @wendelbsilva If by "doesn't work" you mean "yields undefined" then it actually works exactly like it's supposed to. If JS had block-level scope, it would still ReferenceError.

Comment: @wendelbsilva: Sure, if the condition wasn't fulfilled, `Total` would stay `undefined` and the code would throw an error. However, that's not the issue here. The handler is only bound to a the image so the condition is always fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error was using, InnerHTML on TOTAL witch was set like this

```
   var Total = document.getElementById("Total").textContent;
```

Instead of using innerHTML in just

```
var Total = document.getElementById("Total");
```

See here: When you click `#taco1` you add the values to the total.
Try it here:

```js
(function() {

  var T1 = document.querySelector('#taco1');
  T1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === "IMG") {
       var Total = document.getElementById("Total").textContent;
     var price = document.getElementById("p1").textContent;
      var nbrprice = parseInt(price);
      var nbrTotal = parseInt(Total);
      console.log("value of nbrprice is " + nbrprice)
      console.log("nbrprice is a " + typeof(nbrprice));
      console.log("nbrTotal is a " + typeof(nbrTotal));
      var sum = Number(price) + Number(Total);
      console.log("sum is a " + typeof(sum));
      console.log("value of sum is " + sum);;
     var sumtxt = (sum + nbrprice);
      console.log("sumtxt is a " + typeof(sumtxt));
      console.log("value of sumtxt is " + sumtxt);;
      console.log("sumtxt is a " + typeof((sumtxt).toString()));
      console.log("value of sumtxt is " + (sumtxt).toString());;
    document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = sumtxt;
    console.log(sumtxt);
   }
  }, false);

})();
```

```html
<div id='taco1'>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100" width="300" />
  <p>Taco One Price: <span id="p1">4</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div id='taco2'>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x100" width="300" />
  <p>Taco Two Price: <span id="p2">5</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>Total: $<span id="Total">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error, your solution makes complete sense, did the trick and lesson learned.

Comment: If it answers your question, you should accept it as "best answer".

Answer (score 1):

```
var Total = document.getElementById("Total");
//...
var nbrTotal = parseInt(Total.textContent);
//...
Total.innerHTML=sumtxt.toString();
```

Should work

Comment: This breaks `var nbrTotal = parseInt(Total)`

Comment: Then just make parseInt(Total.textContent)

Comment: You still need to say that in your answer. Better yet `parseInt(Total.textContent,10)`

Comment: Done. I would also recommend to have a look at jQuery. Makes things easier!

Comment: Or `Number(Total.textContent)`.

Comment: Yes. I've seen that too but i thought that is obvious then.

Comment: @FabianLurz Easier for who? The programmer, who has to do the work once, or the browser(s), which have to do the work thousands or millions of times depending on the popularity of the page?

Comment: In my opinion it makes things easier for the developer. But ofc it depends on the task. 
And sry i don't understand your last part completly - but probably you want to say that jQuery has less performance then javascript and produces some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Total = document.getElementById("Total").textContent;
// ...
Total.innerHTML = sumtxt.toString();
```

This is expected to work why?

You need to set `innerHTML` of the element in order for that element to update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a textarea. What worked for me was changing the "value" attribute of the component